# I have this shiny code and it's not running effectively. I need help in fixing and making every part of it run

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote this shiny code and want it to calculate the bootstrap and Wilcoxon sign rank tests. I want it modified for every part of the code to run. I got this error when I try running the code
My problem is that after creating the app and I try running it, I get to the setup of the application. Finally, when the application is launching it gives me the following error:

Warning: Error in wilcox.test: unused arguments (sample1, sample2)
1: runApp

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(boot) 
library(stats)


#Bootstrap Test

Define the UI for the app

ui <- fluidPage(

Input fields for the sample data

textInput("sample", "Enter your sample data, separated by commas:", value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"),

Button to trigger the bootstrap calculation

actionButton("bootstrap", "Calculate confidence intervals"),

Output displaying the confidence intervals

textOutput("conf_intervals") )

Define the server logic for the app

server <- function(input, output) {

When the bootstrap button is clicked, calculate the confidence intervals

observeEvent(input$bootstrap, { # Convert the sample data string into a numeric vector sample_data <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$sample, ",")[[1]])
# Use the bootstrap method to calculate confidence intervals for the mean
boot_mean <- boot(sample_data, mean, R = 1000)

# Calculate the 95% confidence intervals for the mean
conf_intervals <- quantile(boot_mean$t, c(0.025, 0.975))

# Display the confidence intervals in the output
output$conf_intervals <- renderText({
  paste("The 95% confidence intervals for the mean are:",
        paste(conf_intervals, collapse = " and "))
})
}) }

##################################################################################### #Wilcoxon Sign Rank Test

Define the UI for the app

ui <- fluidPage(

Input fields for the sample data

textInput("sample1", "Enter the first sample data, separated by commas:", value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"), textInput("sample2", "Enter the second sample data, separated by commas:", value = "2, 3, 4, 5, 6"),

Button to trigger the Wilcoxon test

actionButton("wilcoxon", "Calculate Wilcoxon sign rank test"),

Output displaying the test results

textOutput("test_results") )

Define the server logic for the app

server <- function(input, output) {

When the Wilcoxon button is clicked, calculate the test results

observeEvent(input$wilcoxon, { # Convert the sample data strings into numeric vectors sample1 <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$sample1, ",")[[1]]) sample2 <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$sample2, ",")[[1]])

# Use the wilcox.test function to calculate the Wilcoxon sign rank test
wilcoxon_test <- wilcox.test(sample1, sample2)

# Display the test results in the output
output$test_results <- renderText({
  paste("The Wilcoxon sign rank test results are:",
        "statistic =", wilcoxon_test$statistic,
        "p-value =", wilcoxon_test$p.value)
})
}) }

Run the app

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You cannot have unquoted text in the middle of code. Take all of your non-code commentary (e.g., `Input fields for the sample data`) and wrap them in quotes, likely adding commas as well. If you don't intend for those to be visible in the app, then comment them out with a prepended `#`.

Comment: After that, you likely need to change `wilcox.test(sample1, sample2)` to `wilcox.test(input$sample1, sample2)`, but I have no idea where you expect `sample2` to come from, as it is not defined in code or in shiny html input elements.

Comment: `sample1` and `sample2` are undefined at the point you run the wilcox.test().  Did you mean `input$sample1`?

Answer (score 1):

The code mostly seems to work, with a few tidying edits:

- commenting out comment lines
- uncommenting the `as.numeric` conversion lines:

```r
library(shiny)
library(boot)
library(stats)


#Bootstrap Test

# Define the UI for the app

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Input fields for the sample data
  
  textInput("sample", 
            "Enter your sample data, separated by commas:", 
            value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"),
  
  # Button to trigger the bootstrap calculation
  
  actionButton("bootstrap", "Calculate confidence intervals"),
  
  # Output displaying the confidence intervals
  
  textOutput("conf_intervals")
)

# Define the server logic for the app

server <- function(input, output) {
  # When the bootstrap button is clicked, calculate the confidence intervals
  
  observeEvent(input$bootstrap, {
    # Convert the sample data string into a numeric vector
    sample_data <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$sample, ",")[[1]])
    
    # Use the bootstrap method to calculate confidence intervals for the mean
    boot_mean <- boot(sample_data, mean, R = 1000, trim = 0)
    
    # Calculate the 95% confidence intervals for the mean
    conf_intervals <- quantile(boot_mean$t, c(0.025, 0.975))
    
    # Display the confidence intervals in the output
    output$conf_intervals <- renderText({
      paste(
        "The 95% confidence intervals for the mean are:",
        paste(conf_intervals, collapse = " and ")
      )
    })
  })
}

# Run the bootstrap app

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

###Wilcoxon Sign Rank Test

# Define the UI for the app

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Input fields for the sample data
  
  textInput(
    "sample1",
    "Enter the first sample data, separated by commas:",
    value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
  ),
  textInput(
    "sample2",
    "Enter the second sample data, separated by commas:",
    value = "2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
  ),
  
  # Button to trigger the Wilcoxon test
  
  actionButton("wilcoxon", "Calculate Wilcoxon sign rank test"),
  
  # Output displaying the test results
  
  textOutput("test_results")
)

# Define the server logic for the app

server <- function(input, output) {
  # When the Wilcoxon button is clicked, calculate the test results
  
  observeEvent(input$wilcoxon, {
    # Convert the sample data strings into numeric vectors
    sample1 <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$sample1, ",")[[1]])
    sample2 <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$sample2, ",")[[1]])
    
    # Use the wilcox.test function to calculate the Wilcoxon sign rank test
    wilcoxon_test <- wilcox.test(sample1, sample2)
    
    # Display the test results in the output
    output$test_results <- renderText({
      paste(
        "The Wilcoxon sign rank test results are:",
        "statistic =",
        wilcoxon_test$statistic,
        "p-value =",
        wilcoxon_test$p.value
      )
    })
  })
}

# Run the Wilcoxon app

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```